# Will HTML5 drag and drop work in a Google Apps Script HtmlService?

Tags: drag-and-drop, google-apps-script

I'm messing around with creating a user interface for a Google Apps Script project using an HTML Service, and I've had a request to include drag and drop functionality in this project. I know that there are limitations on these HTML services (I have scoured this document, and it looks like it's saying that native HTML5 drag and drop isn't supported: [Google Apps Script HTML Service Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#html)). Even though the new HTML5 API's aren't officially supported, is there a way I can get drag and drop to work? If not through native HTML5, through an external javascript Library? Or will Caja break the functionality?

My first few attempts haven't worked, so I figured I'd jump on here and see if anyone has any success getting drag and drop to work though some method or another in Google Apps Script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Does work correctly in gas. What have you tried? Draggable etc work just fine using jquery with htmlServices without any special code.